# Save git credintial in linux mint

Tags: github, linux-mint

I am new to the Linux world. When I used Windows, the git credential was saved in my OS and I didn't need to give my username and password every time before pushing or commit or clone from git.

But in Linux Mint I set SSH in my OS and when I clone using SSH link all works well. But when I use https link it asks me to give my username and pass every time before cloning or pushing.

**Is there any way to store my git credential and my Linux mint so that I don't need to give my username and pass every time?**

I am expecting that I could save my git credential in my OS.

Comment: Why don't you just use SSH all the time?

Comment: I use SSH now. But  my curious mind want to know that is there any way just like windows...!